# Uninitialized constant (NameError) problem - how to include a class?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Here is my directory structure:

```
/features/ninja.feature
/features/step_definitions/ninja_steps.rb
/src/ninja.rb
```

When I run

```
cucumber
```

in the root of my project, I get an `uninitialized string constant Ninja (NameError)` error. I've determined it's caused by this line in my `ninja_steps.rb` file:

```
@ninja = Ninja.new :belt_level => belt_level
```

In my `ninja.rb` file:

```
class Ninja
  def initialize (belt_level)
  end
end
```

Do I need to add some sort of `require` at the top of my ninja_steps.rb file, or what? I can't seem to figure out how to do that so that it doesn't bomb out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try adding an include at the top of the ninja_steps? Something like

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../src/ninja")
```

should do the trick. Otherwise, cucumber has no idea what a Ninja is. :)

Comment: "Otherwise, cucumber has no idea what a Ninja is.", which would suit a Ninja just fine. :-)

Comment: this seems...to hard. is there a better way? should i put ninja.rb in a different folder or define some global include or something? I'll have to do this in every *_steps.rb file?

Comment: Brandon, try the -r (or --require flag at the command line). That may also work if you want to keep that info out of your files: cucumber -r src/ninja.rb features

Answer (score 2):

To load all those files in a slightly different way than Bill Turner suggests, taking a hint from projects like cucumber/aruba:

https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/blob/master/features/support/env.rb

```
# env.rb
# add your src dir to the load path
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../src')
require 'ninja'
```