# Uninitialized constant (NameError) in cucumber - how to include a class to _steps.rb?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I apologize first if you feel this is a duplicated question raised 2 years ago. But I tried all kinds answers from stackoverflow or googled out side of stackoverflow, it just doesn't work for me.

My question is pretty much same as the existing one: Uninitialized constant (NameError) problem - how to include a class?
[Uninitialized constant (NameError) problem - how to include a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415101/uninitialized-constant-nameerror-problem-how-to-include-a-class)

My directory structure is:

```
myacc/features/account_bill.feature
myacc/features/step_definitions/account_bill_steps.rb
myacc/features/support/env.rb

myacc/lib/domain_layer.rb
```

Within env.rb: I put various of solutions

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..', '..', 'lib', 'domain_layer')
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../lib/domain_layer")

$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../lib')
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/../../lib/'

require 'domain_layer'
```

In my domain_layer.rb, I wrote:

```
module Domain_Layer
class Account
    attr_accessor :accountid, :service_address, :full_name, :telephone, :email

    def initialize(accountid)
      @accountid = accountid
    end

  end #class

class MyAccount_Web < Account
    def account_number(id)
      return @accountid = id
    end
end #class
end #module
```

In step definitions file, I wrote:

```
Given(/^the account (\d+) has one to five previous bills$/) do |accountid|
  @web_account = MyAccount_Web.new(accountid)
end
```

When I ran command line in the root directory of my project "myacc":

```
cucumber -verbose
```

I got failed on:

```
C:\myacc01>cucumber -verbose
Code:
  * features/support/env.rb
  * features/step_definitions/account_bill_steps.rb

Features:
  * features/account_bill.feature
  * features/account_bill_1.feature
Parsing feature files took 0m0.027s
...
Given the account 03147102942 has one to five previous bills
    uninitialized constant MyAccount_Web (NameError)
```

From cucumber's output, I can see cucumber just doesn't go through the folders claimed in the env.rb, ignoring all the .rb file within lib directory, ignoring the required domain_layer.rb in the lib directory.

I tried to copy all the .rb files into step_definitions folder, but still doesn't work:

```
myacc/features/account_bill.feature
myacc/features/step_definitions/account_bill_steps.rb
myacc/features/step_definitions/domain_layer.rb
myacc/features/support/env.rb

myacc/lib/domain_layer.rb
```

The result:

```
C:\myacc01>cucumber -verbose
Code:
  * features/support/env.rb
  * features/step_definitions/account_bill_steps.rb
  * features/step_definitions/customer_account_bill.rb
  * features/step_definitions/domain_layer.rb
  * features/step_definitions/web_service_layer.rb

Features:
  * features/account_bill.feature
  * features/account_bill_1.feature
Parsing feature files took 0m0.028s
...
Scenario: The account has one to five previous months bills
  Given the account 03147102942 has one to five previous bills
    uninitialized constant MyAccount_Web (NameError)
```

My environment is ruby 1.8.7, cucumber 1.2.1. I assume I did everything I should against all the query result on the internet, is this version/environment issue, or my code is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Heads up.. you are probably going to get flack for using an underscore in a class name. This is frowned upon in ruby.

Comment: thank you guys so much for the feedback. I reviewed my domain layer, found I put class Account and MyAccount_Web within module. By reference of mechanicalfish's comment, I removed the 'module - end' closure, leave only 'class - end' within domain_layer.rb, it just works right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class is defined inside the module you have to access it like this:

```
Domain_Layer::MyAccount_Web
```

Also remove the underscores from class and module names (this is a naming convention).

After that, cleanup your `env.rb`. Simple `require "domain_layer"`should suffice as the lib folder is added to the load path automatically.

Comment: exactly, thank you so much fish. I removed module - end closure, removed underscore with the class name, it works fine now! thanks a lot! :-)